# Prove that if there exist $b,c\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $T^2+bT+cI=0$, then $T$ has an eigenvalue iff $b^2\geq 4c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

This is Exercise 11 from section 9.A of Axler:

Suppose $V$ is a real vector space and $T\in \mathcal L(V)$. Suppose there exist $b,c\in \mathbb R$ such that $T^2+bT+cI=0$. Prove that $T$ has an eigenvalue if and only if $b^2 \geq 4c$.

There is a solution given [here](https://linearalgebras.com/9a.html), but I am not sure about it. Instead of copying it I will briefly state the line of argument:

For brevity, let $\mathfrak T = T^2 +bT + cI$ and let $q(z)=z^2+bz+c$.

1. Complexify $\mathfrak T$ and see that $\mathfrak T_\mathbb C = \mathfrak T = 0$.
2. $q(T_\mathbb C)=0$ if and only if $q$ is a polynomial multiple of the minimum polynomial of $T_\mathcal C$.
3. The minimum polynomial of $T_\mathbb C$ is equivalent to the minimum polynomial of $T$.
4. Eigenvalues of $T$ are precisely the roots of its minimum polynomial.
5. Minimum polynomial of $T$ has a real root if and only if $q$ has a real root.
6. $q$ has a real root if and only if $b^2\geq 4c$.

**Question:** The step that I don't see the justification for is step $5$. I don't see why a polynomial has a real root if and only if any polynomial multiple of it has a real root.

Counterexample I have in mind: Let $p=x^2+1$ and let $q=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$. Then $q$ is a polynomial multiple of $p$, and $q$ has real roots, but $p$ doesn't.

**Edit:** I think I see now. The statement is true for just the polynomial $q$, but not in general. it relies on the fact that $q$ has degree $2$.

Comment: Since $q(z)$ is a quadratic here, either both roots are real or none of them are.

Comment: I figured it out at the same time you commented! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is easier. If a real number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $\lambda^2+b\lambda +c=0,$ Therefore $b^2-4c\ge 0.$

Conversely assume $b^2-4c\ge 0.$ Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ denote the solutions (both real) of the quadratic equation. Then $$(T-\lambda_2I)(T-\lambda_1I)=0$$ Assume $T-\lambda_1I=0.$ Then $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$
If $T-\lambda_1I\neq 0$ there exists $x\in V$ such that $v:=(T-\lambda_1I)x\neq 0.$ Then $(T-\lambda_2I)v=0,$ i.e. $\lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$

The reasoning is valid for finite or infinite dimensional space $V.$